# C# How to check if we've 'had' values from a method without having to re-call the method

Tags: c#

Currently I'm saving the values, gotten from a method, to a variable and using them later on.

This is the example code of how I do it:

```
var events = class.GetEvents();

if(events.Length > 0)
{
     foreach(var event in events)
     {
        // do something
     }
}       
else
{
     // No events
     Console.Log("No Events");
}
```

But actually, What I'd like to achieve is something more like this:

```
foreach(var event in class.GetEvents()) // <-- If none, I'd like to know.
{
      // do something
}
```

However, I still need to log that there weren't any results. I'd have to do a check, and re-call the method to see if there are any results.. OR i++ in my loop, and if that's a 0 => log.

Is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: I proposed this [exact thing on the C# language](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/1025). There's no built-in, intuitive way to do it except how you currently do.

Comment: Well you could create an extension method for `IEnumerable` or whatever your `class.GetEvents()` returns and pass a delegate or some other form of code to handle your else condition. But I don't think that would look much better and complicates reading the code.

Comment: Quick example what you can do with an extension method is a `ForEach` method and call it with the loop statement and an else statement like this: `class.GetEvents().ForEach((event) => { /* loop block */ }, () => { /* else statement */ });`

Comment: What's bad in using variables?

Comment: @xander I love your way of looking at it. I will be using this! ;) Write down the exact same thing as your answer!

Comment: @Paramone it seems Tim did just what I had in mind, see his answer! I was just to lazy to write an answer and gave some hints how you can do it. :)

Comment: @xander Thanks again! Indeed Tim did pretty much the same haha!

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: @SimonForsberg I'm updating my question because it has been put on hold. What would you like to know, my original code?

Comment: I am sorry about your experience with this question being closed, but we prioritize preventing invalidation of answers very highly here. You mentioned in your edit that you included the changes from Tim's answer. Tim reviewed your first edition already, posting another edition of code would be confusing when some answers review different editions.

Comment: I would recommend that you read about [why we don't want example/stub code](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3652). Unfortunately I don't think there's an easy way to get this question away from on hold (one possibility *could* be to add your real original code, how it looked *before* Tim's answer), I would however recommend that you instead focus on making your next question better.

Comment: @SimonForsberg I believe that if those who actually read the question would understand why the, just removed, code is there. 
I don't want to fuss about a question being on hold. However I understand that I should update it with 'my own code'. Still, doing that also gets the changes removed.. So basically what I should do is use my own, un-edited code. I've read why we shouldn't use stub code, but how would that make a difference if using that makes everything easier for everyone.

This isn't a question about ' Why isn't x or y working '. I'm questioning functionality within C#. Thanks tho.

Comment: @Paramone What you should do if you want this question reopened is to use your own, un-edited code, yes. We have had several occurrences on this site of users replying to answers with something like "That's not useful to me because that's not applicable to my real code", which is one of the reasons for putting a question like this on hold exists. We believe that it makes things easier for everyone if we can see the real code, instead of seeing code that has been edited for the purpose of showing it to others. If you want to discuss this more just let me know and I will move discussion to chat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand why you don't want to use a variable. However, one way is to provide an extension method for this:

```
public static void ForEachDo<T>(this IEnumerable<T> seq, Action<T> doWithEveryItem, Action doIfEmpty = null)
{
    bool isEmpty = true;
    foreach (T item in seq)
    {
        isEmpty = false;
        doWithEveryItem(item);
    }
    if (isEmpty && doIfEmpty != null)
        doIfEmpty();
}
```

Now you can use it with everything that implements `IEnumerable<T>` like a `string`:

```
"".ForEachDo(Console.WriteLine, () => Console.WriteLine("No Events")); // prints "No Events"
```

Comment: Perfect! I want my code to be easily readable, functioning and somewhat complex and 'versatile'. I think this is the best answer in terms of my liking.  Using variables are obviously not wrong, but I think it looks way better this way.

Comment: Just one more thing, instead of that bool variable you could also use `if (!seq.Any() && doIfEmpty != null) { doIfEmpty(); return; }` at the top and after that the `foreach`. `INumerable<T>.Any()` should be the same as `INumerable<T>.Length > 0` :)

Comment: @xander: please don't do that. `Enumerable.Any` will check if there's any item. But `seq` could also be a database query which needs an hour to execute. This innocent `Any` would need to execute it completely(if there is no record matching) to evaluate that there is none. After this you are going to enumerate the query again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Debug.WriteIf` method for this.

```
public void Method() 
{
    var events = class.GetEvents();
    Debug.WriteIf(events.Length > 0, "No Events");

    foreach(var event in events)
    {
        // do something
    } 
}
```

You can check it's documentation [here.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debug.writeif(v=vs.110).aspx)

Of course this will be executed only in Debug configuration and will output to Output window, but you can easily borrow the idea for your logger and do the same logic.